# MPMoviePlayerController plays local file but not remote over HTTP

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a mp4 file that as part of the app plays just fine with MPMoviePlayerController.

```
[_mediaPlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                    pathForResource:@"movie" 
                                                    ofType:@"mp4"]]];
[_mediaPlayer play];
```

But once I upload the very same file to a webserver it'll give me that error:

```
Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=2
```

The safari browser on the same device plays the remote movie - so the reachability is not the problem
.
I didn't find any Documentation about what Code 2 tells me. So I am stuck.

Anyone?

Comment: whats the link for the web server file? thats what you should be using as your url. and you should use NSURL URLWithString: because you aren't using a local file path.

Comment: Thank you so much! - That was the hind I needed. It was a rather stupid mistake. I had in my code: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:item.url]; instead of [NSURL URLWithString:item.url];

Comment: @Jesse - put your comment as an answer :)

Comment: @Jakob - when Jesse does, mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use NSURL's `URLWithString`: because you aren't using a local file path.  (posted as answer from comment :))